# Can subscriptions be done with plain websocket?

Tags: java, react-native, websocket

I'm using React Native Expo frontend, Java Spring Boot backend. Expo has only plain websocket support (`new WebSocket("wss://....");`), so I'm using Spring Boot's built in TextWebSocketHandler to handle it.

What I want is essentially STOMP's functionality of subscriptions, like being able to send a message to a subscription board and having all the websocket connections listening on that specific board url receive it. However, I could not find any way online that has implemented such things without STOMP.

Is this possible?

Comment: use this library https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client

Comment: @MuhammadNuman does Expo support it? And SockJS just provides the socket connection if I remember correctly. What I essentially need is STOMP.js but in React Native.

Comment: yes expo support it. yes sockjs is providing only socket connection but you can use this https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket. you dont need to do anything you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stomp/stompjs in expo

Comment: and remember sometimes some client packages don't work on expo but we can compile through install plugin and add into babelrc file

Comment: @MuhammadNuman I don't understand what you mean by "compile through install plugin and add into babelrc file". Could you create an answer and describe these, and I'll give you the 150 rep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `stompjs` by npm or yarn

```
yarn add stompjs
```

then you can use stompjs like this

```
var Stomp = require("stompjs/lib/stomp.js").Stomp;

let client = Stomp.client(url);
client.connect(
  {},
  function connectCallback(frame) {
    console.log("OK");
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("Error");
  }
);
```

**Note:** above code will work

**Extra:** `compile through install plugin` mean some libraries built with node js and our bundler does not make bundle because bundler unable to compile node js library. so we can install nodejs plugin to add support to compile nodejs library.

in our case, stompjs supported client and server so we do not need to add other plugin to execute it. let me know if you have any error

Comment: "install nodejs plugin" where? when? And you're saying I don't need SockJS?

Comment: You could also link some URL describing how to do it and I'll use that.

Comment: @MingleLi you don't need to any plugin for stompjs

Comment: So, StompJS will work even when Expo builds the project for iOS/Android?

Comment: you can use ws://broker.329broker.com:15674/ws or wss://broker.329broker.com:15674/ws

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215424/discussion-between-mingle-li-and-muhammad-numan).